# Create an array of random numbers Return highest number Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning JavaScript and was asked to create a solution to *find and return the largest integer of an array*.

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function largestNumber(numbers) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numbers);
}

console.log(numbers);
largestNumber(numbers);
```

After finding the solution I wanted to expand on the question by *creating a random array first then returning the highest value from it*:

```
function randomArray(length, max) {
  return Array.apply(null, Array(length)).map(function(numbers) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * max);
  });
}

let numbers = randomArray(5, 500)

function largestNumber(numbers) {
  return numbers.map(function(randomArray) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, randomArray);
  });
}

console.log(numbers);
largestNumber([numbers]);
```

While this method solved the question, it lacks the subtlety I was looking for. For instance, is there a way to nest `randomArray()` into `largestNumber()`. Is there a way to call `largestNumber(numbers)` instead of `largestNumber([numbers])`. Feedback for my solution and advice on other possible solutions would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: *"Is there a way to call largestNumber(numbers) instead of largestNumber([numbers])"* - Well you changed `largestNumber()` to expect an array of arrays when you added `.map()` to it. The original function didn't care whether the array you passed it was random or not, there was no need to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there a way to call `largestNumber(numbers)` instead of `largestNumber([numbers])`.*

I'll cover this first because it is the easiest part: simply *don't* change `largestNumber` to use the `.map()` method - that's why it now expects an array of arrays, and returns an array.

Your original `largestNumber()` implementation expected `numbers` to be a one-dimensional array, and this would work on any array of numbers regardless of whether that array was populated randomly or not.

> *is there a way to nest `randomArray()` into `largestNumber()`*

Yes. If you just want to get rid of the intermediate `numbers` variable you can do this:

```
largestNumber(randomArray(5, 500))
```

Or if you meant you wanted to move the random part inside the `largestNumber()` function body, then to have it always generate the same number of possible numbers of the same size you can just directly embed a call to `randomArray(5, 500)` instead of having the `numbers` argument:

```
function largestNumber() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, randomArray(5, 10));
}
```

Or you can make the array length and random number limit arguments of `largestNumber()`:

```
function largestNumber(length, max) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, randomArray(length, max));
}
```

> *Feedback for my solution and advice on other possible solutions would be greatly appreciated*

I would *not* embed `randomArray()` into `largestNumber()`, at least not without renaming the function to `largestRandomNumber()` or something. Better to keep the two functions separate so that they can be used independently.

Comment: Not that it matters much but `Math.max(...a)` is the new `Math.max.apply(null, a)`

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this solution (ES6):

```
const run = (size, max) =>
  Math.max(...[...new Array(size)].map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * max)));
```

where *size* is a random array length and *max* is a randomizer maximum.

This could be easily split into 3 separate methods (and thanks to @Bergi for `Array.from`):

```
const getRandomList = (length, max) => 
  Array.from({length}, () => Math.round(Math.random() * max));
const getMax = (list) => Math.max(...list);
const run = (length, max) => getMax(getRandomList(length, max));
```

Comment: Never knew spreading an empty array can be used instead of `fill`. Very nice.

Comment: I would definitely recommend to use `Array.from({length: size}, () => …)` though. It's shorter, more readable, and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Embrace ES6:

```
const randomArray = (length, max) => {
  return Array(length).fill().map((el) =>{ 
    return Math.round(Math.random() * max)
  })
}

const largestNumber = (numbers) => {
  return Math.max(...numbers)
}

largestNumber(randomArray(5, 500))
```